# jQuery Mobile displays hidden select element

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

See this `select` element with `display:none`. In jQuery Mobile it is displayed despite this:

```
<select id="dddd" name="dddd"
        data-mini="true" data-native-menu="false" data-theme="c"
        onChange=""
        style="display:none">     
  <option value="1">An optinos</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to show/hide jQuery Mobile `select` elements dependent on other user actions hence why I'm doing the above.

Any ideas?

Comment: try to give in id mean #dddd{display:none;}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When your page loads, jQuery Mobile enhances your page to have it the mobile look-and-feel. Unfortunately, there is currently an issue with jQuery mobile that it cannot attach custom classes (and even custom styles, by the style attribute) to enhanced elements. Please check https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3577 for the issue. As a workaround while this issue is still not resolved, you may actually wrap it inside a div element and control the display of the div wrapper instead.

```
<div id="dddd-wrapper" class="ui-screen-hidden">
  <select data-mini="true" data-native-menu="false" id="dddd" name="dddd" data-theme="c"     onChange="" style="display:none">     
    <option value="1">An optinos</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

`ui-screen-hidden` is a jquery mobile defined style rule (in jquery.mobile..css) for hiding an element.