# jquery mobile with angularjs hidden textbox shows a line

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile

When I use angularjs together with jquery mobile, if an input is hidden (set ng-show), the wrapper generated from jquery mobile will show a line.

Please see the jsfiddle I created [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lizhou/mpxfj8aL/3/)

What will be the easiest way to fix this?

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="TodoCtrl" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <a data-role="button" ng-click="visible=true">Show</a>
        <a data-role="button" ng-click="visible=false">Hide</a>
        <br/>
        <input name="test" type="text" placeholder="My input" ng-model="theData" ng-show="visible" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience with jquery mobile but i think that it modifies your html and the result is that your input tag is wrapped with a div. This is the result:

```
<div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
    <input name="test" ... >
</div>
```

the line is the border introduced with .ui-input-text
This cause ng-show to hide the input but not the wrapper.
You can wrap the input in your template in another div and use ng-show on it, in this way the div introduced from jquery will be hidden.

see the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpxfj8aL/22/)

Answer (score 0):

For more information about this problem, have a look at the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968710/jquery-mobile-displays-hidden-select-element) post.

> ui-screen-hidden is a jquery mobile defined style rule (in
>   jquery.mobile..css) for hiding an element.

while the ngHide directive only adds the `.ng-hide{}` css class to your element. That's where the clash happens.