# jquery mobile how to toggle display of select

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I have two drop downs in my app. Initially second drop down box is empty. Based on the selection from first select, then second select is populated dynamically.

I came across this posting [jQuery Mobile displays hidden select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968710/jquery-mobile-displays-hidden-select-element)

As per this posting I was able to hide the second select initially using the ui-screen-hidden is a jquery mobile defined class.

But how do I set display:block when it is populated?

Joe

Answer (score -1):

Remove the class 'ui-screen-hidden' again, when you want to display the element.

You could add an eventhandler to the first dropdown, that removes the class "ui-screen-hidden" when it is changed.

```
$("#dropdown1").change(function() {
    $('#dropdown2').removeClass('ui-screen-hidden');
});
```